# SQL Server : I'm trying to get this table working,

Tags: sql-server, join, dataset

[image]

How do I turn the top dataset into the bottom dataset, so that I can add it to another joined table?

I was trying Cross joins and Pivots but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You also say you've "tried" some things, but you forgot to include those attempts. Show us them and explain *why* they aren't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Please search before asking. [Simple pivot examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) are already on this site numerous times.  Here's another simple example using PIVOT:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
  ID int
  , ChildID int
  , [Name] nvarchar(50)
  , Age int
);

INSERT INTO animals (ID, ChildID, [Name], Age)
VALUES (1, 654, 'Cat', 1)
  , (2, 654, 'Dog', 2)
  , (5, 655, 'Cat', 4)
  , (6, 655, 'Dog', 3)
;

SELECT ChildID
  , PivotTable.[Cat]
  , PivotTable.[Dog]
FROM (
  SELECT ChildID, [Name], Age
  From animals
) as sourceTable
PIVOT (
  SUM([Age])
  FOR [Name] IN ([Cat],[Dog])
) as pivotTable
ORDER BY ChildID
;
```

| ChildID | Cat | Dog |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 654 | 1 | 2 |
| 655 | 4 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WgfgKfXz)

Comment: Hi Thanks you so much for helping me out, I did try the pivot but had this part incorrect    FOR [Name] IN ([Cat],[Dog])    your version worked like a charm x